# Oblivion - Drone sound design...WOW

Tags: design

Outshone some of the acting in my opinion... Drone sounds were so powerful, functional, also had such an air of menace... Brilliant work.

Anywhere I can read about this?

Kind of reminds me of the siren call from War of the Worlds, but with huge balls.

Comment: I totally agree with your comment mate, how can we get the drone sounds into text tones that would be great!!! @Tom

Comment: absolutely agree! awesome tunes and sounds

Comment: I agree. Been trying to find a download so I can use as a notification tone, but no luck as yet. :-(

Comment: Anyone found it? It was awesome.

Comment: Can someone please post the same video link up here? I need to see it one more time. I was looking for the drone sound..don't see it

Comment: I have been loocking for the Drone sound effects from the beginning of the day when Oblivion movie has been shot out first time. Im planning to use them as Windows start up sounds :/
Still cant find any..

Comment: Would totally love some Drone sound alerts on my phone. Anyone found anything?

Comment: To be honest, the drone sound was probably one of the very few cool things about that movie

Comment: Looking for the Drone Locator beacon sound for text notifications. Anyone?

Comment: The drone sounds were the best designed sound effects I can remember.  As you say, definitely added 'an air of menace'.  They slightly reminded me of some of the sound design from Robocop, albeit much better.

Comment: Check out Kyma (by Symbolic Sound).

Comment: Some of the Drone sounds remind me of POCSAG (an asynchronous protocol used to transmit data to pagers). Here's a sample of what POCSAG sounds like when picked up via radio transmission: https://www.rtl-sdr.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/POCSAGAudioExample.mp3?_=1

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree with you guys. The sound design was awesome. And yeah, really reminded me on the "sirens-call" sounds from "war of the worlds".
sounds pretty like granular synthesis and resonance-gain.
I experimented with an EQ and created a resonance, which I have automated.
Thats comes pretty close to some of the Drone Sounds.
Hope they are releasing a sound design making of soon..

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure sound works collection will release a video about Oblivion real soon. I haven't seen the film as yet, but I heard a lot of great reviews about its sound design.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see the movie yet, but the trailer looks spectacular. Hopefully it's not the same as with Prometheus which dissapointed as actual film, whilst the trailer was great.
Here's a link to the soundtrack by M83 (french musician/composer). http://3voor12.vpro.nl/luisterpaal/albums/M83.html
Maybe he also worked on the drones your talking about?

Answer (score 1):

http://soundworkscollection.com/videos/oblivion

edit: they don't show anything on sound design actually in this video :/

Answer (score 1):

Exclusive SoundWorks Collection profile we talk with Director Joe Kosinski about the sound and music of his new film "Oblivion".…

https://vimeo.com/64213430

Comment: OK, Tks, but these sounds were token from the original sound track, so its impure , it has noises from other elements!!! a Pity!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a clip on soundcloud.  Here it is...

https://soundcloud.com/demsoff/drone-sound-from-oblivion

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest ones I fund so far:
http://www.freesound.org/people/drzhnn/packs/12752/

Enjoy!

Answer (score -3):

Pretty Good quality 55 second splice of various drone sounds, search the 'ol 'Tube for:

Oblivion Drone Sounds HIGH QUALITY.

Never been here before but I'm guessing you guys know how to capture & cut/splice/loop whatever you want from it. I prefer sound forge for that sort of stuff.

REALLY hoping for a legit, clean share of the various drone audios from the developer, instead of having to rely on what others have pulled from the film.  Have looked exhaustively. Maybe some hope when the film actually releases to disc? Maybe someone has the ability to contact the right person?

Keep looking guys. Are we such a marginal group to want access to this stuff?

Comment: Please keep in mind that SSD is not about exchanging copyright-protected material.

Answer (score -3):

Exactly what you guys want.. Download direct from my Google drive

https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B5LOh5HYjbe2N2ZGZE01c1BncTQ/edit

Comment: Please keep in mind that SSD is not about exchanging copyright-protected material.

Answer (score -4):

There's a drone sound effects pack available on this website:

http://obelysk.co.uk/oblivion

Enjoy!